# Inserting foreign key in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is the code that i am using for serializer

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    addedBy = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='addedBy.username')
    country = CountrySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('id','name','slug','country','addedBy','createdAt')

class ActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    tag = ActivityTagSerializer()
    location = CitySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ('id','title','slug','description','location','tag','owner','createdAt')
```

i am able to insert data if i remove tag and location serializer by adding there `pk` in form but not with them being serialized. Here is the views that are being used

```
class ActivityList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Activity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ActivitySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

class ActivityDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Activity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ActivitySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

The owner field is read-only so thats why had to create a separate insert for the same. Now here are the outputs from the two case , with and without reference to other serializer (tag and location) in ActivitySerializer

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "sdfsdf",
    "slug": "sdfsdf",
    "description": "sdfsdfsdf",
    "location": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "goa",
        "slug": "goa",
        "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "india",
            "slug": "india",
            "addedBy": "georoot",
            "createdAt": "2016-06-17T05:56:30.099121Z"
        },
        "addedBy": "georoot",
        "createdAt": "2016-06-17T06:01:12.771079Z"
    },
    "tag": {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "temp",
        "slug": "temp",
        "addedBy": "georoot",
        "createdAt": "2016-06-17T06:03:44.647455Z"
    },
    "owner": "georoot",
    "createdAt": "2016-06-17T06:24:50.006344Z"
}
```

This is with reference to serializer which is the output view that i want, but insert not working in this case

and this is without reference to the serializer

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "sdfsdf",
    "slug": "sdfsdf",
    "description": "sdfsdfsdf",
    "location": 2,
    "tag": 3,
    "owner": "georoot",
    "createdAt": "2016-06-17T06:24:50.006344Z"
}
```

Here i can change the values of tag and location by passing in the `pk`.
How can i do the same while referencing to other serializer as in the previous output

### EDIT

structure for models

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    addedBy = models.ForeignKey('auth.user')
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

class Activity(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.user')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    description = models.TextField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(City)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(ActivityTag)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: What is the question about? Is it about serialising a foreign key object?

Comment: No, thats already done, its about inserting the same. It is not working when i reference activityTagSerializer and citySerializer in first part of code

Comment: *inserting the same*, did you mean creating a model or updating a model?

Comment: @John put & post both are not working. I tried with json input in DRF. Although i must confess this is my first time with foreign key in same so i am not sure what is the proper way to post. One thing that i did mentions that if i remove the serializer class and then post the `pk` the foreign key sets properly.